# Nested UIScrollViews with paging and zooming

Tags: ios, swift, nested, uiscrollview

I have an outer scrollView and multiple inner scrollViews as shown in the following image.

`OuterScrollView` - **Paging enabled** **vertical** scrollView (shown in green Colour). Only **two-finger** scrolling allowed.

`InnerScrollView` - able to zoom. Only **two-finger** scrolling allowed.

If I perform vertical swiping, then `OuterscrollView` paging works as expected. But Let's say I have zoomed a particular `innerScrollView` such that it's content (cat image) is bigger than the `innerScrollView` bounds. Now I try to swipe vertically. then I want this `innerScrollView` to scroll to it's max range first before allowing the OuterscrollView to scroll. How I can do this?

I thought I should enable/disable `isScrollEnabled` property of the `outerScrollerView` when `innerScrollView` reach it's max range. But couldn't get it done to work consistently with both directions (up & down).

Here is the GitHub project: https://github.com/Basnagoda/NestedScrollViewsWithPaging

[image]